# Cannot read property 'join' of null

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, and I don't get what's wrong with my code. Tried many variations, but each time, I'd get the wrong result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>acronyms</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka the Great">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid col-sm-4">
<h1>Something</h1>
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="userInput" id="userInput" class="form-control input-normal" placeholder="Enter Text Here" ng-model="userInput">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div>The acronym for "{{userInput}}" is <span main-directive id="result" ng-bind="acronymOutput"></span></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
        myApp.directive("mainDirective", function(){
            var inputValue = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
            var matches = inputValue.match(/\b(\w)/g);
            var acronymOutput = matches.join("").toUpperCase();
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = acronymOutput;
            document.getElementById("userInput").value = ("");
            return {
                template: ("<h1>" + acronymOutput + "</h1>")
            };
        })
```

Comment: Yeah, you're not creating a directive properly. Angular JS docs have extensive information on directives...

Comment: Read documentation, learn directives, fix code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bind the input response to a model, pass that model to your directive and process it from there

Comment: You can pass models to directives using the `require` attribute

Answer (score 0):

please check `var matches` after match with reg. expr.

```
var matches = inputValue.match(/\b(\w)/g);
console.log(matches); // check in console
var mnemonicOutput="";
if(typeof matches == "array")
{
   mnemonicOutput = matches.join("").toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help at all. I want the application to work, not to know where my error is. I already know where the error is since it's pointing out that it's null. @Haresh Vidja

Answer (score 0):

You can write in this way.

```
Array.isArray(matches) && matches.join("").toUpperCase();
```

OR

```
Object.prototype.toString.call( someVar ) === '[object Array]' && matches.join("").toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use regex to create an acronym?
If so, I think it's best to split by " " and then join.
Replace these two lines:

```
var matches = inputValue.match(/\b(\w)/g);
var mnemonicOutput = matches.join("").toUpperCase();
```

With this:

```
var matches = inputValue. split(' ').map(function(item){return item[0]}).join('');
var mnemonicOutput = matches.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you make first is to use a `directive` when you need to trigger an input value to a controller function.
Just pass the value in an `ng-model`, process it and get it back.

```js
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.controller("AcronymController", function($scope) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.getAcronym = function() {
        var matches = vm.userInput.match(/\b(\w)/g);
        vm.acronymOutput = matches.join("").toUpperCase();
        document.getElementById("userInput").value = ("");
      };
    });
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9zL5nj8e/1/